# Perforce P4Perl Api installs in wrong directory

Tags: perl, perforce

I have two Perl versions installations on my PC, `5.12.3` and `5.16.3`. To install the `P4Perl API`, I needed to set in Path the location of Perl `5.16.3`(otherwise I was getting a P4Perl API installer error) and after succesfully running the installation, I searched for the `P4.pm` module and noticed that the installation of the `P4.pm` module was done in the folder of the `5.12.3` installation.

As you can see in the title, the installation was done for Perl 5.16
[image]

But if I search for the `P4.pm`, it is located in the `5123` folder ( which is coresponding to `Perl 5.12.3`
[image]

Even more, when I try to run a simple script which only imports the `P4.pm` module:
-with `Perl 5.16.3` it complains about the missing `P4.pm` module
-with `Perl 5.12.3` it complains about the missing `perl516.dll` which I can find with `Everything` in the installation of `Perl 5.16.3`.

[image]

After this, I thought to move the content which was installed in `5.12.3` installation to the `5.16.3` installation, just as @Gerhard suggested. And now it works. Does anyone knows why it messes up at installation?

Even though, the files exist physically.

Comment: Why not just copy the module directories to the relevant folders /site/lib and /lib

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I was just doing that, please check my update.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I missed some files earlier, now it works on `5.16.3` after I move the folders which you suggested. But it's still confusing what may have caused this.

Comment: well, you somewhere it still saw your initial perl path as the main perl to use.

Comment: I will post an answer quick with more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the Directories of the module files to the `<PATH_TO_PERL>/lib` and `<PATH_TO_PERL>/site/lib` to solve the issue.

Perl modules almost always exists as `/lib/DIR/DIR/Module.pm`
for instance `C:\perl64\lib\Date\Simple\date.pm`
If the files exists on their own, the there is a problem with the module installation itself. Or, Somewhere there is a path reference to your old perl version directory.

To see which perl path is used by default, do:

```
perl -e "print $^X"
```

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Well, the default points to the right `5.16.3` installation path, but as you mentioned, maybe somewhere there is an old refference to the `5.12.3` installation path. Thanks for the answer, Gerhard.